# Is it possible to skip building raster attribute table for unique value symbology in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, symbology

I need to visualize a raster image in ArcGIS Pro. This image is quite large and I need to display it with a "unique value" value symbology. I have another layer with the same symbology and the same classes, but I cannot import it before building the raster attribute table (which takes a long time). Is there a way to skip building this table in order to quickly visualize my raster ?